# How to test mass email script

Tags: wordpress, email, testing

I have more than 3000 members on a site built using wordpress. I am going to send mass emails like newsletters or notifications on a new post etc. How can I test my script to send mass emails ? I already have script that is sending emails but I wanna see its performance and limitations. Like How this will perform when tested with 5000 members. I don't want to send test emails to registered members. I am looking for a testing tool that can simulate this all and let me know if I am good to go. Thank you.

Comment: I know this is not what you are asking for, but why not just use mailchimp or something similar. Mass emails can be difficult to get right and you could end up having your server blacklisted for spamming. Mailchimp is free for 2000 emails and otherwise good value and includes all sorts of stats on email openings and links clicked.

Comment: @ZweiBlumen: +1 Interesting workaround.

Comment: I 'll use AWS SES for sending emails but would not like to go live without testing. anyway to simulate/test mass emailing ???

Comment: Might be a better fit for serverfault.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have Amazon SES services, you should be able to point the script to the Sandbox settings and test away.  No email gets delivered but SES and Wordpress will be stress tested.